# How to use another function's return value as an argument for another function? Name Error found

Tags: python, function, nameerror

i'm a beginner in python and I've been stuck in this problem. I'm trying to use the return value of one function as an argument to the other but I would get a name error:

```
NameError: name 'azi' is not defined
```

this is my code

```
 def convert(bear1):
     azi = []
     dms = []
     dd1 = []
     for x in bear1:
         a = x.split(" ")
         b = a[1].split("-")
         dms = [float(m) for m in b]
         d, m, s = dms
         dd = d + float(m)/60 + float(s)/3600

         if "N" in a and "W" in a:
             az = 180 - dd
             azi.append(az)
        
         elif "S" in a and "W" in a:
             az = dd
             azi.append(az)
        
         elif "N" in a and "E" in a:
             az = 180 + dd
             azi.append(az)
       
         elif "S" in a and "E" in a:
             az = 360 - dd
             azi.append(az)
     return azi

def latdep(dist1, azi):
     azi = convert(bear1)
     lat = []
     dep = []
     for dst, ang in zip(dist1, azi):
         lat.append(-dst * math.cos(math.radians(ang)))
         dep.append(-dst * math.sin(math.radians(ang)))
     return lat, dep
```

thank you!

Comment: You don't show how you're calling *latdep()*. You're also overriding *azi* immediately you start running *latdep()* meaning that the second argument passed to that function is irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a function, you have to define which variables are going to be used by the function, `def(var1, var2, ...)`. In your `latdep` function, it seems you want azi to be what the convert function returns, however you are trying to define this within the function rather than in the var2 position. (As commented) your first line in latdep overrides your azi input.

IIUC, You want to remove the line `azi = convert(bear1)` from latdep, and call the function as below (assuming dist1 and bear1 are already defined):

```
latdep(dist1, convert(bear1))
```

Comment: @nostalgiaultra if this or one of the other answers helped, it would be great if you could accept it (tick mark on the left)

Answer (score 1):

```py
def convert(bear1):
    # ...

def latdep(dist1, azi):
    # remove the 'azi' line
    lat = []
    dep = []
    for dst, ang in zip(dist1, azi):
        lat.append(-dst * math.cos(math.radians(ang)))
        dep.append(-dst * math.sin(math.radians(ang)))
    return lat, dep




dist1 = # define dist1
bear1 = # define bear1
latdep(dist1, convert(bear1))
```